# Set GeoServer's password encryption to "Strong PBE" via REST API

Tags: geoserver, geoserver-rest-api, security, encryption

On GeoServer 2.24.2 I want to set the password encryption to "Strong PBE" via REST API.

In the GUI one can navigate "Settings" -> "Security":

[image]

I do not want to do this via the Web-UI but using the REST API. I found no suitable endpoint on https://docs.geoserver.org/2.24.x/en/user/rest/index.html

How can I do this?

Comment: Why would you like to do that? It is a more or less static configuration. Only reason I can think of is when deploying  a lot of instances and you don't want to configure each instance manually. In that case it's probably easier to edit the configuration files before deploying the data_dir folder.

Comment: I am writing a small GeoServer configuration tool as Python script against the REST API and this was one of the few things I did not figure out. I'd love to avoid any manual XML fiddling/uploading via SSH.

Comment: I understand. My thought was that this setting would not have to been changed in runtime so no need to upload the setting file. It would have been done once and for all before deploying to the production environment.